# Is it possible to develop for .NET framework v4.0 using Visual Studio Community?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET project which is currently targeting .NET Framework 4.5. Due to the fact that it'll be deployed on Windows Server 2003, it needs to be downgraded to v4.0 (the last supported version according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx.

I'm aware that both versions can't be run side-by-side... is it possible to uninstall v4.5 on my version of Visual Studio Community and replace it with v4? Are there any other workarounds?

Comment: Don't get yourself in trouble for such tricky configuration. The time spent on configuration cost more than the price of latest windows.

Comment: Windows Server 2003 is end of life. So unless your company purchased extended support, you have no good reason to target it. Everything else should be on .NET 4.5.2 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4.5 and 4.0 both target the same CLR version, which is 4.0. You can have the compiler target 4.0 by changing the project settings. You don't need to uninstall anything.

Comment: Updated the original question to mention that it needs to support Windows Server 2003. Would this still work if the target framework is 4.5?

Comment: If 4.5 doesn't work on 2003, then no. I mean, if you don't happen to use any of the 4.5-only classes, then it should work. That's risky though. Either target 4.0 directly, or get your Windows updated.